# Python AST library to get all assignment statements

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking into Python's `ast` library to traverse the AST and get all assignments. How can I walk the tree to only get the assignment statements in python using `ast` library?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) and the `visit_Assign` and `visit_AugAssign` methods. Here's a quick demonstration:

```
import ast
import inspect

def f():
    a = 1
    # Something else
    print("test")
    a += 1

class CustomNodeTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        print("\nvisit_Assign")
        print(node.__dict__)
        print(node.targets[0].__dict__)
        print(node.value.__dict__)
        return node
    def visit_AugAssign(self, node):
        print("\nvisit_AugAssign")
        print(node.__dict__)
        print(node.target.__dict__)
        print(node.value.__dict__)
        return node

nodes = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f))
CustomNodeTransformer().visit(nodes)
```

Which prints:

```
visit_Assign
{'targets': [<_ast.Name object at 0x7fdca78a10b8>], 'value': <_ast.Num object at 0x7fdca78a1080>, 'lineno': 2, 'col_offset': 4}
{'id': 'a', 'ctx': <_ast.Store object at 0x7fdca78b0198>, 'lineno': 2, 'col_offset': 4}
{'n': 1, 'lineno': 2, 'col_offset': 8}

visit_AugAssign
{'target': <_ast.Name object at 0x7fdca7585048>, 'op': <_ast.Add object at 0x7fdca78b0f60>, 'value': <_ast.Num object at 0x7fdca7585080>, 'lineno': 5, 'col_offset': 4}
{'id': 'a', 'ctx': <_ast.Store object at 0x7fdca78b0198>, 'lineno': 5, 'col_offset': 4}
{'n': 1, 'lineno': 5, 'col_offset': 9}
```

Regarding the example:

- The nodes of the AST tree are taken from the source code of function `f` as an example. You can use any tree you like.
- `visit_Assign` has a list `targets` in case of assignments like `a = b = 1`. The example just uses `targets[0]`.
- `NodeTransformer` is meant to change the nodes. So without `return` in the methods above, it would be like `return None` which will remove the nodes from the tree.
- If none of your code is supposed to change anything of the nodes, then there's no need to use `ast.NodeTransformer` anyway, and you could just use [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) instead. Then you don't need `return`.

Comment: If you don't want to change the nodes, why not subclass the NodeVisitor class?